# Cast exception while setting name

Tags: java

I am getting a cast exception while setting the name.

```
        Object[] customers= customerRepository.getCustomerName(Id);     
        Customer row = new Customer();          
        row.setName((String) customers[0]+" "+(String) customers[1]);
```

The exception is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: Could you add the exception your receiving to the question?

Comment: @CyanAngel    HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: It means customers array holds objects that are not of type String. So casting to String fails.

Comment: What is the value of `customers[0].getClass().getName()`?

Comment: This looks like you should be using Generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So no one bothered to read the exception message?

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The leading `[` indicates that the class is an array class.

What you're getting above is:

```
row.setName(((String) customers)[0]+" "+((String) customers)[1]);
```

Cast has precedence over array indexing.

Comment: The exception wasn't included in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Try use it

```
customer[0].toString()
```